# Array and Using Array Combine in Php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have two full arrays, of about 10 values each.  I have combining those arrays and displaying them through this line of code.

```
foreach(array_combine($hpictures, $highschools) as $pictures => $hschool)
```

and echoing them out into a css format.

The array's combine and code works perfectly the only problem is that for some reason it is only displaying of the values in the array, and not going through and displaying all 10.  I am wondering if the foreach or array_combine is the reason for this.

Edits:

```
       if(!empty($highschools)){
               echo "<h3>High School Division</h3>";
               echo "<ul>";
                foreach(array_combine($hpictures, $highschools) as $pictures => $hschool){
                        echo "<li><img src='$pictures'/><a href='./schoolpage.php?school=$hschool'><strong>$hschool</strong></a></li>";
                    }



               echo "</ul>";
               }
```

Thanks for any help, and hope this is helpful to others as well.

Comment: Can you post more code? Example arrays and also how you're outputting the values?

Comment: start with `print_r(array_combine($hpictures, $highschools));`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want array_merge() instead? array_combine() assumes you have one array of keys and one array of values

Comment: I have made edits and added more code. @dagon I did that and it displays the when the arrays combine there are only three values but seperatly there are 10. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the structure of your data, all I can assume is you may need array_merge() instead of array_combine()

```
foreach(array_merge($hpictures, $highschools) as $pictures => $hschool)
```

And for a complex array strucure, try array_merge_recursive()

```
foreach(array_merge_recursive($hpictures, $highschools) as $pictures => $hschool)
```

**Differences**

```
array_combine(array('dog','cat'),array('fred','felix'))
```

would make an array like:

```
array('dog'=>'fred','cat'=>'felix')
```

where as

```
array_merge(array('dog','cat'),array('fred','felix'))
```

would produce

```
array('dog','cat','fred','felix');
```

Comment: I tried array merge and that worked but displayed the pictures and text each as a list item.  Should I merge them and them run THEN through a foreach loop?

Comment: I think we really need to see the structure of your arrays to understand the problem better. It may even require manual iteration and assignment through the two arrays.

Comment: The array_merge worked. Can you maybe explain the difference real fast, so I can better understand?